# Bedrohen mit oder von?

Tags: word-usage, preposition

This sentence appears in today's [DW Langsam gesprochene Nachrichten](https://www.dw.com/de/deutsch-lernen/nachrichten/s-8030):

> Mindestens 60 Prozent der Erwachsenen sollen jährlich Fortbildungskurse belegen und die Zahl der Menschen, die **von** Armut und sozialer Ausgrenzung bedroht sind, soll um mindestens 15 Millionen sinken.

However, the only preposition that Duden indicates to be used with bedrohen is **mit**. Is this sentence grammatically correct, and if so, why?

A second question about this sentence. In English we would say, "...should decline to no more than 15M." But the German sentence appears to say, "...should decline to at least 15M." Why is it not written as, "..., soll um nicht mehr als 15M sinken." or something similar?

Comment: Only one question per question, please ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the 2 questions should be split, to judge the 2 answers independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### *mit* vs. *von*

The use of *mit* comes from *bedrohen* itself, while *von* comes from the passive voice. It's not an either-or relationship, because they are not mutually exclusive and have different meanings.

Let's start with the active voice first. In the simplest case, we have neither *mit* nor *von*:

> - Der Räuber bedroht den [Kasper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasperle).
>   *The robber threatens Kasper. (literally)*
> - Armut bedroht die Menschen.
>   *Poverty threatens the people. (figuratively)*

Chiefly in the literal meaning, *mit* can indicate the **instrument** the threatening is carried out with:

> Der Räuber bedroht den Kasper **mit der Pistole**.
> *The robberer threatens Kasper with a pistol.*

*Von*, on the other hand, can only appear in the passive voice. Hence, the phrase **bedrohen von* doesn't exist, but it's possible to construct a similar phrase with the passive infinitive: *bedroht werden (von …)*. But for a start, the basic passive would be:

> Der Kasper wird bedroht.
> *Kasper is threatened*.

*Von* then tells us **who** threatens:

> - Der Kasper wird **vom** *(=von dem)* **Räuber** bedroht.
>   *Kasper is threatened by the robberer. (literally)*
> - Die Menschen werden **von Armut** bedroht.
>   *The people are threatened by poverty. (figuratively)*

For the **instrument**, we can have *mit* in the same way as in the active in the passive voice, too:

> Der Kasper wird **mit der Pistole** bedroht.
> *Kasper is threatened with a pistol.*

And hence, whenever we can use *mit* in the active, we can as well use both of them in the passive:

> Der Kasper wird **vom** Räuber **mit** einer Pistole bedroht.
> *Kasper is threatened by the robberer with a pistol*.

---

#### *sinken auf* vs. *sinken um*

The answer to your second question (which actually should have been asked separately) is in fact not about *mindestens* vs. *höchstens*, but about *sinken auf* vs. *sinken um*:

> - Die Zahl der von Armut Bedrohten soll **um mindestens** 15 Millionen sinken.
>   *The number of those threatened by poverty should decrease **by at least** 15 million.*
> - Die Zahl der von Armut Bedrohten soll **auf höchstens** 15 Millionen sinken.
>   *The number of those threatened by poverty should decrease **to not more than** 15 million.*

Arguably, the following slightly changed word order would be possible with *mindestens* and *auf* if you consider the decrease a number that should be as big as possible:

> Die Zahl der von Armut Bedrohten soll **mindestens auf** 15 Millionen sinken.
> *The number of those threatened by poverty should decrease **at least to** 15 million.*

Your example would mean (**caveat:** has an probably unintended meaning, not recommended to use):

> Die Zahl der von Armut Bedrohten soll um nicht mehr als 15 Millionen sinken. [sic!]
> *The number of people threatened by poverty should decrease by not more [sic!] than 15 million.*

Comment: Wonderfully clear and helpful explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Man sollte eine Frage erst schließen, um sie aufsplitten zu lassen, statt sie  zu beantworten und damit den Anreiz, die Aufteilung auch durchzuführen, herauszunehmen, und das Problem im Kontext der Antwort zu kritisieren.

Comment: @userunknown Sure (cf. my [meta question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/) on that), but the "incentive" was already gone since there have been two other answers addressing *both* points and not mentioning it. Seeing that it didn't seem practical to move the other answers in parts ex post, I considered it most useful for everyone to answer and add a friendly hint for next time. Hence, I'm wondering why you commented on this answer particularly, and if that has something to do with the downvote since I'm positive that this doesn't make the answer less useful to anybody.

Answer (score 3):

I am a bit puzzled by your question, because English makes the same distinction:

> He was threatened **with** a gun.
>
> Er wurde **mit** einer Waffe bedroht.

but

> He was threatened **by** Peter.
>
> Er wurde **von** Peter bedroht.

The semantic distinction is that the first form states **what** he was threatened with, whereas the second form states **who** was doing the threatening.

Therefore

> mit Armut bedroht
>
> threatened with poverty

is a weird turn of phrase, because it implies that somebody was threatening to make someone poor (something like a robbery, or the threat of lawsuit).

In contrast

> von Armut bedroht
>
> threatened by poverty

grammatically means that poverty is doing the threatening. There is no implied other actor that deliberately tries to make someone poor. That is, poverty is being seen as something that arises on its own rather than through human intent.

As for your second question, you got the preposition wrong:

> soll **um** mindestens 15 Millionen sinken

means

> should be reduced **by** at least 15 million

Comment: Good answer, which might be improved by adding that *bedrohen durch* is a strong indication for passive voice, so the full construction is  *bedroht werden durch*.

Answer (score 2):

"To threaten with" is "bedrohen mit", yes, but this here is simply the normal "von" construction for a *passive*, independent of the particular verb: They're not threatened *with*, but *by* poverty and social exclusion.

("Sinken *um*" also is "drop *by*", not "to".)